# Порядок выполнения needle

Tags: javascript, node.js

Помогите пожалуйста с порядком выполнения. Не могу понять, как сделать порядок выполнения

Есть такой код:

```
var needle = require("needle");
var arr = ["1","2","3"];
var arr2 = ["1e","2e","3e"];

    needle.get("https://www.google.com", function(){
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
        console.log(arr[i]);   
        needle.get("https://www.google.com", function(){
        for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        console.log(arr2[i]);
        }
        });
    }
  });
```

Нужно чтобы после срабатывания этого кода результат был следующим:

```
1
1e
2e
3e
2
1e
2e
3e
3
1e
2e
3e
```

А получается вот так

```
1
2
3
1e
2e
3e
1e
2e
3e
1e
2e
3e
```

Comment: Я конечно ошибку очевидную помог исправить, но асинхронность это не отменяет. Я поищу еще как это исправить.

Answer (score 2):

В needle есть поддержка [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), попробуйте так:

```js
// для демонстрации
const needle = {
  get(idx) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, parseInt(Math.random() * 100))
    });
  }
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = ["1e", "2e", "3e"]

needle.get('https://www.google.com').then(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    needle.get('https://www.google.com').then(() => {
      console.log(arr[i])
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        console.log(arr2[j])
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Если надо все прям по порядку:

```js
// для демонстрации
const needle = {
  get(idx) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, parseInt(Math.random() * 100))
    });
  }
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const arr2 = ["1e", "2e", "3e"]

needle.get('https://www.google.com').then(() => {
  let lastPromise
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let currPromise = needle.get('https://www.google.com')
    
    if (!lastPromise)
      lastPromise = currPromise

      lastPromise.then(() => {
        console.log(arr[i])
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          console.log(arr2[j])
        }
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Все равно не получается :(

Comment: это я не так код чуть написал, исправил

Comment: Ну и что? Если второй запрос по какой-то причине выполнится первее первого, то порядок нарушится

Comment: Тогда массив arr будет без индекса - undefined :) https://repl.it/@maxtaines/UselessSardonicThing

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ZanyUnusualDictionaries специально гонку устроил, что бы показать, что не соблюдается порядок

Comment: Вообще я делаю парсер и первый needle это товар который я получаю из каталога , а так же у этого товара есть размер и цвет ( у других размеров разные цвета) , а второй needle это и есть размер

Comment: @m3xTa1nes а вам важен порядок 1 2 3? или только что бы за за первым шли три соответствующих

Comment: Получается так , что мне из текущего товара нужно получить размер. И должно быть в нормальном порядке типа: 
`Товар 1 Размер S
Товар 1 Размер M
Товар 1 Размер XL
Товар 1 Размер XLL

Товар 2 Размер S
Товар 2 Размер M
Товар 2 Размер XL
Товар 2 Размер XLL`

Comment: @ThisMan Порядок первого массива не важен , главное чтобы у первого массива были все элементы второго массива